# How to setup a simple Ruby on Rails application using the Fedora Ruby stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fedora

How can I setup a Rails application using yum installed packages?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't do that. I can't imagine any valid reason not to use some kind of Ruby version management software -Maybe that's my ignorance if so, please enlighten me-.

If you decide to use [RVM](http://rvm.io) -which is perfectly documented, supported, updated bla bla bla..-

Just install it without any pain using this command:

```
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

After installation completed, you're free to install as much as Ruby versions to your system without any conflict concerns... Installing a Ruby version is as easy as this (No dependency worries!!):

```
$ rvm install 2.1
```

After this step is done too, you can make it default:

```
$ rvm use 2.1 --default
```

And from now on, using [gemset](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics)s you have the power of freedom!

If you don't want to create any specific gemsets, you are free to use default one without setting anything. To create a Rails app?

```
$ gem install rails
$ rails new myApp
```

Cheers. But wait...

Please... Just don't use stack Rubies.

Update: [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) is another great option!

Comment: This is correct. You should be taking care of your own ruby / gems management, and not rely on any OS packages for ruby/rails/gems. Also, I vote rbenv is preferable over rvm.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't include **sudo yum install ruby-devel**, you get error message, can't find ruby.h.

Comment: That should be 'sudo yum install ruby-devel' not 'sudo yum install reby-devel'